# How to check internet speed in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I was trying to code a small project to check the internet speed. The code to check the internet speed works very well but when I added some GUI it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

The code to check the internet speed is here:

```
    import speedtest


    def check():
       test = speedtest.Speedtest()
       down = test.download()
       up = test.upload()
       print(f"Download Speed: {down}\n Upload Speed :{up}")


   check()
```

But when I added GUI to it, it gives me the above error.

The code of GUI is here:

```
    import kivy
    import Checker
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
          f = FloatLayout()

          b = Button(text="Check Speed")
          b.size_hint = (0.4, 0.2)
          b.pos_hint = {'x': 0.3, 'top': 0.5}
          b.bind(on_press=Checker.check())
          f.add_widget(b)


          return f

      if __name__ == "__main__":
     MyApp().run()
```

And the error for this code is here:

```
AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Please help me someone with this.

---

**EDIT:**

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/rajnish gupta/PycharmProjects/kivy_new_Pro/speed_test.py", line 2, in <module> 
   import speedtest 
File "C:\Users\rajnish gupta\PycharmProjects\kivy_new_Pro\venv\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 180, in <module> 
  _py3_utf8_stderr = _Py3Utf8Output(sys.stderr) 
File "C:\Users\rajnish gupta\PycharmProjects\kivy_new_Pro\venv\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 166, in init 
   buf = FileIO(f.fileno(), 'w') 
AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: BTW: in all GUIs buttons/binds need function name without `()` - it is called `"callback"` - `b.bind(on_press=Checker.check)` - and when you press button then Python uses `()` to run it. Now you use `check()` so it runs it when you start program.

Comment: I have removed the brackets but the error remains the same.

Comment: and the error : " Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/rajnish gupta/PycharmProjects/kivy_new_Pro/speed_test.py", line 2, in <module>
     import speedtest   File "C:\Users\rajnish gupta\PycharmProjects\kivy_new_Pro\venv\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 180, in <module>
     _py3_utf8_stderr = _Py3Utf8Output(sys.stderr)
   File "C:\Users\rajnish gupta\PycharmProjects\kivy_new_Pro\venv\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 166, in __init__
     buf = FileIO(f.fileno(), 'w')
 AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
"

Comment: read my first comment again - `put ... in question (not comment)` - it will be more readable and all people will see it. People may not read comments.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the () from the bind assignment to `Checker.check`.  Also, (as @furas said), it will execute when you first import `Checker.py` into your gui program so you should probably remove the call from the bottom of `Checker.py`, or use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block at the bottom of `Checker.py`.

Comment: error message may means that `speedtest` needs access to "standard error" (`sys.stderr`) to display results in console/terminal but maybe `Kivy` assigns own class to `sys.stderr` to catch all errors but it seems this class doesn't have all needed functions - it doesn't have function `fileno()`. The only idea to check source code of `speedtest` and if it short then use it to write own version which doesn't use `sys.stderr`. BTW: full error shows you full path to speedtest.py with source code.

Comment: I tested code on LInux Mint 19.2 with Python 3.7.7, Kivy 1.11.1 (without `venv`, `PyCharm`)  and don't get this error. If I use `b.bind(on_press=Checker.check)` and `def check(event=None)` then I even get result after pressing button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code works if I put all code in one file. But not when code is in separated files.

It seems `Kivy` catch `sys.stderr` (probably to catch errors displayed on console/terminal/shell) and later `speedtest` has problem to run some code.

Solution is to import `Checker` before `kivy`. This way `speedtest` is imported before `kivy`

```
import Checker
import kivy
```

---

**BTW:**

`Button` needs functions name without `()` - it is called `"callback"` - and when you press button then `kivy` uses `()` to run this function

```
b.bind(on_press=Checker.check)
```

But when it runs this function then it also sends `event` as argument so your function has to get it.

```
def check(event):
```

But then you may need default value to run it in old way without argument

```
def check(event=None):
```

Or simly use

```
def check(*args):
```

And then you can still run it in `Checker.py` as

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Testing speed ...")
    check()
```

---

**checker.py** (I prefer lower case name)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import speedtest

def check(*args):  # has to get arguments to run with `bind()`
    test = speedtest.Speedtest()
    down = test.download()
    up   = test.upload()
    print('Download Speed: {:5.2f} Mb'.format( down/(1024*1024) ))
    print('  Upload Speed: {:5.2f} Mb'.format(   up/(1024*1024) ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Testing speed ...")
    check()
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import checker  # has to be before `import kivy`
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
      f = FloatLayout()

      b = Button(text="Check Speed")
      b.size_hint = (0.4, 0.2)
      b.pos_hint = {'x': 0.3, 'top': 0.5}
      b.bind(on_press=checker.check)  # without ()
      f.add_widget(b)

      return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
     MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @furas it really worked.Thank you for giving your time and answering my question.